# Передать параметр из base.html, обработать его, и вернуть в context_processor flask

Tags: python, flask

Есть такой HTML находящийся в base.html

Задача: при выборе одного элемента из списка, либо применить фильтр, либо сделать выборку из базы.
Я понимаю, как это сделать при помощи AJAX или SiJAX, но в этом случае нужно указывать route, а так как дело идёт в base.html, из которого наследуются все прочие страницы, route использовать не получается.

```
<div class="currenty-converter">
    <form method="post" action="single-product.html#" id="currency-set">
        <div class="current-currency">
            <span class="cur-label">Отображать цены в: </span><strong>{{price}}</strong>
        </div>
        <ul class="currency-list currency-toogle">
            <li>
            <a title="Dollar (USD)" href="">Долларах (USD) </a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a title="Rubles (BYN)" href="">Рублях (BYN)</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

`{{price}}` находится в `context_processor`, и я думал пытаться решить как-то через него, но теперь понимаю, что так не получится.

Так же есть `update_template_context`, но я не понимаю, как этим пользоваться.

Comment: Я так и не понял, что вам мешает заюзать route. Да, это нужно делать именно через AJAX

Comment: А на какой route мне слать? 
Форма, представленная в примере, находится в base.html, параметры, берущиеся из базы, находятся в context_processor.
Задача сделать динамику не на какой-то отдельной странице, а на ВСЕХ страницах, то есть в base,html

Comment: route разный на разных страницах, что ли, или в чём проблема? Но даже в таком случае можно вызвать `url_for` во вьюхе и передать получившийся адрес в шаблон как переменную

Comment: @andreymal, не совсем понял, что значит "передать получившийся адрес в шаблон как переменную", но да, route разный.

Если использовать SiJAX или AJAX, то придётся к каждому роуту писать один и тот же код. 
Мне бы хотелось, чтобы я мог делать то же самое, но по отношению к переменным, находящимся в context_processor.

Comment: Переменные из context_processor должны быть успешно доступны и в base.html. Или вы что-то не так делаете, или я чего-то не понимаю потому что вы чего-то не договариваете, или всё сразу

Comment: Переменные доступны, но как их менять, скажем, при нажатии на кнопку?

Comment: Переменные в шаблоне - никак, только ещё один HTTP-запрос отправлять с нужными вам параметрами

Answer (score 1):

Работает, без `context_processor`, и не совсем так как нужно, но работает :) :

```
<div class="currenty-converter">
    <form method="post" action="" id="currency-set">
        <div class="current-currency">
            <span class="cur-label">Отображать цены в: </span><strong>{{request.args.get('v')}}</strong>

        </div>
        <ul class="currency-list currency-toogle">
            <li>
                <a title="Dollar (USD)" href="{{url_for(request.endpoint, v='USD')}}">Долларах (USD) </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="Rubles (BYN)" href="{{url_for(request.endpoint, v='BYN')}}">Рублях (BYN)</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

Осталось только понять, как этот сделать так, чтобы этот параметр по умолчанию присутствовал на всех страницах, а добавление других параметров в GET не удаляло его.